Finiteness of Ideal Class Group in Ring of Integers of Number Field
In Number Fields by Daniel A. Marcus, he proves the finiteness of the ideal class group in a ring of integers by showing that each ideal class has only finitely many members. I don't see how this implies finiteness of the whole group. Could there not be infinitely many classes each with only finitely many members?

Definitely does not prove that; it's false in $\mathbb{Z}$! (Where the unique class of ideals has infinitely many ideals, namely all the nonzero ones). You are misreading the statement proven.

Chapter 5, Corollary 2 of Marcus states that "There are only finitely many ideal classes in R."
In fact, each ideal class will have infinitely many members. For example, all principal ideals form the identity class in the class group and there are infinitely many principal ideals.
